# Paypal IPN giving me HTTP 200 response code but says INVALID?

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using the Sandbox version of Paypal and in every transaction I get the same HTTP response code 200 with this as the output.

```
mc_gross=4.99&protection_eligibility=Eligible&address_status=confirmed&payer_id=89DUDR3H8QUZ6&tax=0.00&address_street=1 Maire-Victorin&payment_date=23:57:24 Sep 11, 2015 PDT&payment_status=Completed&charset=windows-1252&address_zip=M5A 1E1&first_name=test&mc_fee=0.44&address_country_code=CA&address_name=test buyer&notify_version=3.8&custom=&payer_status=verified&business=billing-facilitator@REMOVED.REOMVED&address_country=Canada&address_city=Toronto&quantity=1&verify_sign=AtzgbXK1X.9xdTmY4kIxKn.3Mc4LA0AZU0o3yoMH-W9PB0pDU-ial8ml&payer_email=billing-buyer@ctstudios.ca&txn_id=91220841NA400993W&payment_type=instant&last_name=buyer&address_state=Ontario&receiver_email=billing-facilitator@ctstudios.ca&payment_fee=&receiver_id=2EEUCVJ5AHKJS&txn_type=web_accept&item_name=Bronze Package&mc_currency=CAD&item_number=WP01&residence_country=CA&test_ipn=1&handling_amount=0.00&transaction_subject=&payment_gross=&shipping=0.00&ipn_track_id=cfe9b900ce627
```

And when it redirects to the page, it echos this

```
The response from IPN was: INVALID
```

This is my code to check the header.

```
if ($_GET['page'] == "order_completed") {

    $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
    $myPost = array();
    foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
      $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
      if (count($keyval) == 2)
         $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
    }

    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
       $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
    } 
    foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
       if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
       } else {
            $value = urlencode($value);
       }
       $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }


    $ch = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
    if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
        curl_close($ch);
        exit;
    }

    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
        $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
        $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
        $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
        $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
        $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
        $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
        $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
        $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
          echo $key." = ". $value."<br>";
        }
    } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
        echo "The response from IPN was: <b>" .$res ."</b>";
    }

    curl_close($ch);
}
```

My question is, why am I getting a Response Code 200 but it says the response was INVALID?

Comment: ...and your question is?

Comment: My question is, why does it say the response from IPN was invalid...

Comment: No one has any idea on what I'm doing wrong? :(

Comment: If you want to delete your question - there should be a button for that. If there isn't, flag your post for moderator attention and request deletion. Explain _why_ you want it deleted in the flag. Alternatively, you can ask to have the post dissociated from your account.